# Using postFeedItemWithMentions I can't set visibility "AllUsers"

Tags: apex, feeditem, visibility

I'm trying to create a chatter post via Apex.
The problem I'm facing with is the visibility in the partner community.
The user mentioned remains highlighted in Gray.

In the FeedItem record what I can see is that NetworkScope is correctly set to "AllNetworks" but Visibility is set to "InternalUsers" instead of "AllUsers".

**Does anyone know how I can make visibility set to "AllUser" ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code so that we can help*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) class. It's not officially supported by Salesforce, although it was initially written by me (I'm a Salesforce employee).

Currently there isn't an option to control the visibility, but since the source code is available, it's easy to add. Look for the code that creates the `ConnectApi.FeedItemInput`:

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
input.body = messageInput;
input.subjectId = subjectId;
```

You'll want to add a parameter that lets you specify the `ConnectApi.FeedItemVisibilityType`. It can be either `ConnectApi.FeedItemVisibilityType.InternalUsers` (the default) or `ConnectApi.FeedItemVisibilityType.AllUsers`.

```
input.visibility = your_new_parameter
```

Here are the Apex docs about [ConnectApi.FeedItemVisibilityType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_enums.htm#FeedItemTypeVisEnum) and [ConnectApi.FeedItemInput](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_input_feedItem.htm).

I added this as an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper/issues/3) in the ConnectApiHelper GitHub repo. I'll address it when I have some free time, unless someone beats me to it. (Feel free to send a pull request my way!)

Comment: Thanks @alouie this solved my problem. Unfortunately now I'm facing with a new problem. If the Apex code had been triggered by a partner community user I got an Error: "System.NoAccessException".

Comment: Are you passing in the community ID as the first parameter to ConnectApiHelper.postFeedItemWithMentions()? If so, how are you getting the community ID?

Comment: This is the query I use to get the community Id:  >Network nw = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name = 'XYZ' Limit 1];  >String CommId = String.ValueOf(nw.Id);  >ConnectApiHelper.postFeedItemWithMentions(CommId,'701260000006CKb','{00526000000Fww9} ti è stato assegnato un nuovo task.');

Comment: That looks good to me. I'd double-check that the partner community user has access to both the campaign record (701260000006CKb) and the community (XYZ).